# Storing multiple integers in an array with a single input C++

Tags: c++

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV1JH.png)

```
constexpr int SIZE = 500; /* I don't know how to create an array with infinite amount of slots. And it's unreasonable to expect the user to input more than 500 coordinates */

int x_arr[SIZE] = { 0 };

int y_arr[SIZE] = { 0 };

double d = 0.0;

int i = 0; 

cout << "Enter the points:" << endl;

while(cin >> d) {

    int xy_arr[2] = { 0 };

    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        cin >> xy_arr[j];
    }
    x_arr[i] = xy_arr[0];
    y_arr[i] = xy_arr[1];

    i = i + 1;
}

for(int n = 0; n <= i; n++) {
        cout << x_arr[n] << y_arr[n] << endl;
}
```

I want the xy_array to store two integers (x and y), i.e a coordinate.
Look at it as a temporary array to siphon integers to the x_array and y_array.

I want an array of x-coordinates and y-coordinates respectively. But the user must input the x-coordinate and y-coordinate as a single input. And they may input as many coordinates as they wish.
For example:
Enter the points:

5 4

5 6

2 3

4 4

etc ...

And after each iteration the xy_array resets, so new integers can be inserted.

I don't understand why this code doesn't work.

Comment: Please post code as code, not as an image. Thank you!

Comment: You also require the user to enter `d` on every iteration. What's that for? Again, on every iteration you input three numbers, not two: one double and two integers.

Comment: I want the loop to break as soon as the user inputs a non-number. The loop will continue only as long as the inputs are numbers.

Comment: Where are `x_arr` and `y_arr` declared? You need to show **all** your code.

Comment: I removed c >> d in my while-condition. So now I cant get the loop to break when the user inputs STOP

Comment: Please update your question with a description of *how* this case doesn't work. The question will be of no use to future readers if they cannot recognize if their problem matches yours.

Answer (score 2):

1. *"I don't know how to create an array with infinite amount of slots."*

Such a thing is not possible, but C++ has containers that can grow (they reallocate new memory dynamically under the hood), e.g. `std::vector`.

2. *"And it's unreasonable to expect the user to input more than 500 coordinates"*

Welcome to the number one cause of every fatal system crash, security vulnerability and other bug.  Never trust user input and always expect your users to be unreasonable.

3. `while(cin >> d)`

You read in 3 values. `d`, `x` and `y`. Thus if your user doesn't explicitly enter 3 values for each pair of coordinates, `d` will alternatingly swallow away `x` and `y` values. So when the user inputs the following:

> 5 4
>   5 6
>   2 3
>   4 4

you will actually end up with:

> 4 5
>   2 3
>   4

Instead you want to read in only 2 values (`x` and `y`), so you should rewrite your loop to `while(std::cin >> x >> y)`

4. I would suggest making one array of a custom type `Coordinate`, which holds an `x` and a `y` member, instead of 2 arrays.

---

All in all something like this should work:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int doTheThing()
{
    std::vector<Coordinate> coordinates;

    std::cout << "Enter the points:" << std::endl;

    int x, y;
    while (std::cin >> x >> y)
    {
        coordinates.push_back({ x, y });
    }

    for (auto coordinate : coordinates)
    {
        std::cout << coordinate.x << ", " << coordinate.y << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To complete **Max Vollmer**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58159999/7598851), here's a solution that stops on "STOP" command (asked in a comment to OP):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct Coordinate {
  int x;
  int y;
};

int main() {
  std::vector<Coordinate> coordinates;

  std::cout << "Enter the points:" << std::endl;

  std::string input;
  while (std::getline(std::cin, input) && input != "STOP") {
    std::istringstream iss;
    iss.str(input);

    int x, y;
    if (iss >> x >> y) {
      coordinates.push_back({ x, y });
    } else {
      std::cout << "Invalid input: " << input << std::endl;
    }
  }

  for (auto coordinate : coordinates) {
    std::cout << coordinate.x << ", " << coordinate.y << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

User input is read with [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline) to a string which is first compared to "STOP" and only if this fails (i.e. the input is something else, presumably a set of coordinates), it is used to feed an [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) from which both coordinates can be extracted.